# Problems with creating mwArray

Tags: c++, matlab

I am trying to create `mwArray` according to examples:

```
double data[] = {1,4,2,5,3,6};
mwArray C(2, 3, data); // matrix constructor
```

second line gives an error:

`error: C2664: 'mwArray::mwArray(array_ref *,bool)' : cannot convert argument 3 from 'double [6]' to 'mxClassID' There is no context in which this conversion is possible`

I can create array wiht single element without errors:

```
mwArray xx = mwArray(1);
```

so, how to solve that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no constructor that takes data for initialization. Instead, [the docs suggest](http://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/cxx/mwarray.html#zmw57dd0e11114) to use `SetData`:

```
mwArray C(2, 3, mxDOUBLE_CLASS);
C.SetData(data, 6);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Various Matrix Library functions require or return an mxClassID argument. mxClassID identifies how the mxArray represents its data elements.

Got it from [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxclassid.html)

So, possible solution is to rewrite your declaration like this:

```
mwArray C(2, 3, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, data);
```

Comment: it gives the same error. I have looked `mclcppxlass.h` where definitions of `msArray`s constructors are located. There no constructor like this: **mwArray(mwSize num_rows, mwSize num_cols, mxClassID* data)**. It seems that such constructor have been removed

Comment: It can't give you the same error - here is 4 arguments while you pass 3 - it can't be the same error.